# Cassandra: Get table partitioner name using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra has 3 partitioners:

Murmur3Partitioner
RandomPartitioner
ByteOrderedPartitioner

This can be set using the YAML file, but is there any cql query that I fire to find out which partitioner the table is using to generate the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

A) Use below cqlsh command.

cqlsh:ah300001> describe cluster;

Cluster: Cluster1

**Partitione**r: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

B) ah300001> nodetool describecluster

Cluster Information:

```
Name: Cluster1
Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
**Partitioner**: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```